# Using Font Awesome Pro with Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, angular, google-app-engine, npm

How does one get Font Awesome Pro to work on Google's App Engine in the standard environment?

I've included the .npmrc file with the proper registry settings and authentication token:

```
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

However after I deploy the code, I get the following:

```
Step #1 - "builder": npm ERR! code E404
Step #1 - "builder": npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@fortawesome%2ffontawesome-pro - Not found
Step #1 - "builder": npm ERR! 404 
Step #1 - "builder": npm ERR! 404  '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro@^5.12.1' is not in the npm registry.
Step #1 - "builder": npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
Step #1 - "builder": npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'workspace'
Step #1 - "builder": npm ERR! 404 
Step #1 - "builder": npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
Step #1 - "builder": npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Step #1 - "builder": npm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2020-02-10T16_36_28_563Z-debug.log
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR    error: `gen_package_lock` returned code: 1
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     gen_package_lock took 13 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     builder initialization took 13 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     full build took 13 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR    `gen_package_lock` had stderr output:
Step #1 - "builder": npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
Step #1 - "builder": npm ERR! code E404
Step #1 - "builder": npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@fortawesome%2ffontawesome-pro - Not found
Step #1 - "builder": npm ERR! 404 
Step #1 - "builder": npm ERR! 404  '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro@^5.12.1' is not in the npm registry.
Step #1 - "builder": npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
Step #1 - "builder": npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'workspace'
Step #1 - "builder": npm ERR! 404 
Step #1 - "builder": npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
Step #1 - "builder": npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
Step #1 - "builder":
```

Apparently it's not recognizing the .npmrc as the URL endpoint still points to https://registry.npmjs.org. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered this was because of my .gcloudignore file. I need to exclude the .npmrc file being ignored.